# Перевод статьи из справки "What browsers do we support?"

Tags: поддержка, предложение, статус-завершено, локализация, справка

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/browser-support

---

### Какие браузеры мы поддерживаем?

Stack Overflow поддерживает две последние стабильные версии основных браузеров. Сюда не входят beta/dev-версии.

Поддерживаемые нами браузеры можно [визуализировать](https://browserl.ist/?q=last%202%20versions%2C%20not%20ie%20%3C%2011%2C%20not%20dead%2C%20not%20op_mini%20all%2C%20not%20baidu%20%3E%200%2C%20not%20and_ff%20%3E%200%2C%20not%20and_qq%20%3E%200%2C%20not%20kaios%20%3E%200%2C%20not%20op_mob%20%3E%200%2C%20not%20ie_mob%20%3E%200%2C%20not%20and_uc%20%3E%200%2C%20not%20Samsung%20%3E%200%2C%20not%20Android%20%3E%200) с помощью [Browserlist](https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist).

Если вашего браузера нет в этом списке, сайт всё ещё может работать, но с некоторыми недочётами.

Comment: Мобильный Firefox не поддерживают? Вот бяки

Comment: @andreymal может ошибка. Спросил на [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336824/260198).

Comment: Может и не поддерживают. Но как любитель мозиллы я пользуюсь и на телефоне и вполне работает нормально, глюков не замечал. А поддерживают ли -- это на их усмотрение.

Comment: @AK [не поддерживают](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336826/260198).