# Отсутствует перевод раздела справки об очередях проверок

Tags: дефект, локализация, очередь-проверок, справка

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: related:https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10896/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f

Comment: @VictorVosMottor набиралось на отдельный раздел, и из репутационно/модераторского раздела убрали

Comment: Ага. Лучше б перевели ;)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor перевести-то можно, но встроить всё равно могут только начиная от модераторов и выше

Comment: а кто выше модераторов?

Comment: @Danis сотрудники компании вестимо. Вот взгляните на [этот профиль](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/6/nicolas-chabanovsky), например.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ модераторы не могут.

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik вот [здесь](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9981/176217) кто правил? Или [тут](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9682/176217)?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ КМ лично даёт доступ к справке на редактирование. Единовременно можно дать доступ к нескольким статьям. У меня был доступ на правку 2-3 статей в справке.