# Пожалуйста, помогите перевести страницы справки про очереди проверки на русский язык

Tags: обсуждение, локализация, очередь-проверок

В этом году мы начали [улучшать очереди проверки](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346901/improving-the-review-queues-project-overview). Важным шагом к улучшению является создание нового раздела справки про сами очереди.

#### Зачем это нужно?

Большинство информации про очереди проверки собрано в вики публикациях на MSE. Эти статьи содержат много деталей и нюансов, разобраться с которыми начинающему участнику может быть сложно. Цель этой инициативы — создать место куда мы сможем направлять участников, начинающих работать с очередями проверки, чтобы они могли быстро понять основные механики работы конкретной очереди.

#### Пожалуйста, помогите перевести страницы справки про очереди проверки на русский язык

Несколько недель назад мы создали первые версии страниц справки и [опубликовали их на MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356120/274323) для сбора отзывов. Доработанные версии мы [добавили в справочный центр](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/review-queues) всех сайтов сети, в том числе [Stack Overflow на Русском](/help/review-queues)

В ответах к этому вопросу я опубликовал текущие версии новых страниц справки на английском языке. Мы будем вам очень признательны, если вы поможете перевести их на русский язык. Мы верим, что только сами участник могут создать корректный перевод, который будет понятен другим участникам Stack Overflow на русском. По мере готовности переводов, я буду добавлять их справочный центр.

Пожалуйста, не стесняйтесь улучшать уже имеющийся перевод! При необходимости изменяйте формулировки так, чтобы описание читалось естественно и понятно. Я постараюсь своевременно обновлять страницы справки после внесения улучшений.

#### Страницы справки про очереди проверки

- ✅[What are review queues?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/11115/6)
- ✅[Why was I suspended from the Review Queues?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/11116/6)
- ✅[How do I use the Low-quality posts queue?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/11117/6)
- ✅[How do I use the First posts queue?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/11118/6)
- ✅[How do I use the Suggested edits queue?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/11119/6)
- [How do I use the Close votes queue?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/11120/6)
- [How do I use the Reopen votes queue?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/11121/6)
- [How do I use the Late Answers queue?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/11122/6)

Comment: Сам дефект об отсутствии перевода описан [тут](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11065/176217).

Comment: Английскую версию можно удалить? Или пусть будет для сравнения?

Comment: Первый пошел ;)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor Подскажите, думаете можно добавлять результат в справку?

Comment: Может быть. Я точно не знаю. Я например не перевел заголовок "Basic Workflow". Я чего то не знаю как это по-русски ;)

Comment: Везде, во всех предложенных переводах, название очереди встраивается в текст. Мне это кажется некорректным. По-моему, вместо `Что такое очереди проверок?` было бы правильнее писАть как `Что такое "Очереди проверок"?` (в соответствии с заголовком выпадающего меню), или вместо `Как мне использовать очередь сообщений низкого качества?` писАть `Как мне использовать очередь "Сообщения низкого качества"?` (в соответствии с наименованием пункта меню).

Comment: @VictorVosMottor *Я например не перевел заголовок "Basic Workflow". Я чего то не знаю как это по-русски* Типичный/обычный порядок действий.

Comment: Добавил в справочный центр две готовые страницы.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Я полностью перевел все статьи, которые были не переведены (а именно 2-я, 4-я, 5-я, 6-я, 7-я, 8-я). Переводы могут содержать незамеченные мной опечатки. Переводил как можно ближе к тексту. Названия очередей проверок и другие термины взял такими, какие они есть уже переведенные. Отмечу, что я так же не знаю, как перевести `Basic Workflow`,  так что там уж сами решайте. Я (вместе с моим [другом](https://translate.yandex.ru/?from=tabbar&lang=en-ru)) предлагаю перевод: Основы рабочего процесса:)... В общем, можете проверить все мои переводы и добавлять на сайт:):):)

Comment: @МаксимФисман Огромное спасибо! В ближайшее время вычитаю на опечатки и добавлю в справочный центр.

Comment: Когда переводы будут добавлены на сайт?

Comment: @Danis Посмотрел, надо вычитывать сообщения. Постараюсь постепенно добавлять. Если вы сможете вычитать пару сообщений, будет очень здорово и существенно ускорит процесс.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Не совсем понял, зачем был откат вопроса к версии с 2 переведенными вопросами, если переведены все (просто не проверены), но хотелось бы поинтересоваться, сколько уже проверено? Когда мы сможем увидеть переводы на сайте?

Comment: @МаксимФисман Спасибо за вопрос! Этот список помогает мне отслеживать, сколько переводов уже добавлено на сайт. Текущие переводы хорошо сделаны, но все еще [требуют согласования](https://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1032/6) с остальным справочным центром. Перевод — штука не простая =)

Answer (score 6):

Очень старался, но это еще черново. Если я чего упустил или какие притензии, пишите в комменты!

> #### Как использовать очередь проверок "Сообщения низкого качества".
>
> *Необходимо набрать $Privilege-PostEditing единиц репутации*\
> Сообщения попадают в очередь проверок "Сообщения низкого качества"
> из-за того, что они [были отмечены
> тревогой](/help/privileges/flag-posts)  участниками как проблематичные
> или определены системой проверки качества как потенциально
> низкокачественные. Причинами могут быть:
>
> - Вопрос или ответ слишком короток, написан не на том языке или содержит тарабарщину.
> - Новые или уточняющие вопросы написаны в виде ответов.
> - Ответы, которые не содержат попыток ответить на заданный вопрос или содержат только ссылки и не содержат объяснений.
> - Комментарии, написанные как ответы («У меня
>   тот же вопрос» или «большое те спасибо, выручил!»).
>
> Важно помнить, что неправильный ответ не является «низкокачественным»
> по нашему определению. Неправильные ответы должны получать
> комментарий, объясняющий, что не так с этим ответом, или должны быть
> получить голос против, но не тревогу.
>
> ### Основная последовательность действий
>
> Сначала проверьте, является ли сообщение вопросом или ответом; оно
> будет помечено как «Вопрос» или «Ответ» сверху. В большинстве случаев
> это будут ответы.
>
> - Выберите **Выглядит нормально** для вопросов по теме, достаточно подробных.
>   и не слишком общих. Используйте эту же опцию для ответов на
>   вопрос, которые являются ответами, даже если они могут быть неверными.
> - **Править**, если сообщение хорошего качества, но вы можете отредактировать его, чтобы улучшить его. Избегайте редактирования
>   сообщений, которые следует закрыть или удалить, так как это приведет к
>   удалению публикации из очереди проверок.
> - **Рекомендовать удаление** или **Удалить**, если вы считаете, что ответ вообще не касается вопроса, содержит только ссылку или
>   непонятен. Не голосуйте за удаление просто неправильных ответов. Вы
>   можете оставить комментарий, объясняющий что не так  с ответом, или
>   выбрать один из предоставленных шаблонных комментариев.
> - **Рекомендовать закрытие** или **Закрыть**, если вы считаете, что вопрос должен быть закрыт (см. [What does it mean if a question is
>   "closed"?](/help/closed-questions)
> - **Пропустить**, если вы не уверены в качестве сообщения.
>
> Часть содержимого этой страницы адаптирована из информации в  [Meta
> Stack Exchange FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180029), который
> также содержит более подробные инструкции, если вам интересно узнать
> больше об этой очереди.

Comment: Я думал, что в общих ответах надо публиковать переводы.

Comment: Да? А если кто-то еще захочет свой вариант предложить? ;)

Comment: Ну, ответ же общий, пусть предлагает на здоровье))

Comment: «содержат тарабарщину»?) Может, лучше заменить на «бессмыслицу»?)

Comment: Внес несколько мелких правок сразу в ответ - опечатки, грамматика и т.д.

Answer (score 4):

✅ Полностью переведено
‍⚖️ Утверждено и добавлено.

---

#### What are review queues?

One of the ways that the community moderates the site is by reviewing posts that have been identified by users or the system as needing review to help determine whether the contribution is beneficial to the site. Once you have achieved $Privilege-AccessReviewQueues reputation, you have access to the first set of Review queues – and you’ll gain access to more as your reputation increases.

Review queues show you posts one at a time, so that you can evaluate what, if any, action is needed. Each queue is equipped with distinct options so that you may take appropriate action – in one, you may be looking at the first posts by new users. In another, edits suggested by lower-reputation users or assessing questions to determine if they should be closed or reopened.

Each queue has a specific purpose and each of the following Help center pages will help you learn more about how to review in each queue:

- [First posts](/help/review-first-posts) - $Privilege-AccessReviewQueues reputation. The First Posts queue contains the first posts made by users. These posts may need special attention because the users are not familiar with site quality rules.
- [Late answers](/help/review-late-answers) - $Privilege-AccessReviewQueues reputation. This queue contains answers that were posted much later than the question. Reviewing these posts makes sure that great new answers get seen and problematic answers get removed.
- [Triage](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-triage) – Stack Overflow only - 500 reputation. The primary goal of Triage is to quickly sort questions into groups: good as is, needs community editing, or should be closed/flagged.
- [Help and improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-help-and-improvement) - Stack Overflow only - 2,000 reputation. This queue lets you edit questions that were flagged in Triage as needing community editing.
- [Low quality posts](/help/review-low-quality) - $Privilege-PostEditing reputation. This queue contains posts that were determined to be of low quality based on a system-generated quality score and/or user flags.
- [Suggested edits](/help/review-suggested-edits) - $Privilege-PostEditing reputation. Editing other people's posts requires $Privilege-PostEditing reputation. When users without enough reputation submit an edit, their proposed changes go into this queue.
- [Close votes](/help/review-close) - $Privilege-CloseQuestion reputation. When questions aren’t a good fit for our format or scope, they need to be closed. Questions with active close votes or close flags show up in this queue so that others can review whether they should be closed.
- [Reopen votes](/help/review-reopen) - $Privilege-CloseQuestion reputation. When closed questions get edited, or if others disagree with the closure, they can be reopened. Questions with active reopen votes, as well as questions whose bodies have been edited during the first 70 days since they were closed appear in this queue.

Note: The First posts and Late answers queues do not exist on [Meta sites](/help/whats-meta).

#### Что такое очереди проверок?

Один из способов, которым сообщество модерирует сайт — проверка сообщений, идентифицированных пользователями или системой, как нуждающихся в проверке, с тем, чтобы помочь определить  являются ли такие посты полезными для сайта. Как только вы наберете $Privilege-AccessReviewQueues баллов репутации, вы получите доступ к первым очередям проверок. Вы будете получать доступ к другим очередям по мере увеличения Вашей репутации.

В очереди проверок вы увидите один пост за раз, поэтому сможете оценить какие действия, если таковые требуются, необходимы. Каждая очередь имеет различные возможности, так что Вы можете принять соответствующие меры. В одной, вы можете проверять первые посты новых пользователей, в другой —  улучшать правки, предложенные участниками сообщества с более низкой, чем ваша, репутацией, оценивать должны ли вопросы быть закрыты или же наоборот открыты заново.

Каждая очередь создана с определенной целью, и каждая из следующих страниц Справочного центра поможет Вам узнать больше о том, как проводить проверку в каждой из очередей:

- [Первые сообщения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/review-first-posts) — $Privilege-AccessReviewQueues баллов репутации. Очередь первых сообщений содержит первые сообщения пользователей. Эти сообщения могут нуждаться в особом внимании, поскольку пользователи еще не ознакомились с правилами качества сайта.
- [Запоздалые ответы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/review-late-answers) — $Privilege-AccessReviewQueues баллов репутации. Эта очередь содержит ответы, которые были опубликованы, намного позже вопросов. Обзор таких  постов, обеспечивает, что хорошие новые ответы увидят, а проблемные — удалят.
- [Сортировка](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-triage) — доступна только на Stack Overflow — 500 баллов репутации. Основная цель сортировки заключается в том, чтобы быстро разделить вопросы на группы: хороший вопрос, нуждается в редактировании сообществом, должен быть закрыт/отмечен тревогой.
- [Помощь и улучшение](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-help-and-improvement) — только Stack Overflow — 2000 баллов репутации. Эта очередь позволяет Вам редактировать вопросы, которые были помечены в сортировке, как нуждающиеся в редактировании сообщества.
- [Сообщения низкого качества](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality) —  $Privilege-PostEditing баллов репутации. Эта очередь содержит сообщения, которые были определены системой, как низкокачественные, основываясь на сгенерированных системой баллах качества и/или на тревогах от пользователей.
- [Предлагаемые правки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/review-suggested-edits) — $Privilege-PostEditing баллов репутации. Редактирование сообщений других людей требует $Privilege-PostEditing баллов репутации. Когда пользователь без достаточного количества репутации предлагает правку, она попадает в эту очередь.
- [Голоса за закрытие](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/review-close) —  $Privilege-CloseQuestion баллов репутации. Когда вопросы не подходят для нашего формата или тематики, они должны быть закрыты. Вопросы с большим количеством голосов или тревогами за закрытие показываются в этой очереди, чтобы другие участники смогли рассмотреть, стоит ли закрывать такие вопросы.
- [Голоса за повторное открытие](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/review-reopen) —  $Privilege-CloseQuestion баллов репутации. Когда закрытые вопросы дополняются, или если другие участники не согласны с закрытием, такие вопросы они могут быть открыты заново. Вопросы с большим количеством голосов за повторное открытие, а так же вопросы, содержание которых было отредактировано на протяжении первых 70 дней после их закрытия появляются в этой очереди.

Примечание: на [сайтах меты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) не существует очередей первых сообщений и запоздалых ответов.

Comment: @Akina Это же общий ответ. Подключайтесь)) За запятыми и правда не следил

Answer (score 2):

[статус-завершено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be)

---

#### Why was I suspended from the Review Queues?

*Learn more about [what the review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work) are and how they work.*

Review suspensions are not penalties, but temporary holds on your reviewing privilege. The purpose of this is to give you time to learn more about how to review correctly. Poor reviews negatively effect the community and the site’s content. If you take incorrect action on multiple tasks, your reviewing privilege may be temporarily suspended and you won’t have access to the Reviews Queue during this time period.

If you are suspended, you will see a suspension message in the Review Queue navigational dropdown. A more detailed message will be available to you in the [Review Queue dashboard](/review) and in the queues. This message will remain for the duration of your suspension.

[image: Screenshot of the Review Queue dropdown in two states, first, during a suspension where the review suspension message ("Notice Review privileges suspended - Your review privileges are suspended until Jul 24. Click to learn more.") is visible but none of the review queues are and second after the suspension is over but the review message ("Notice Review privileges suspended - Your review privileges were suspended for 7 days. Click to learn more") is still visible.]

You may have been suspended between visits to the site. Although your suspension has expired, you will still be notified that the suspension occurred. Review and acknowledge the message and the notification will be dismissed.

### What can I do in the meantime?

Read the suspension notice carefully. Revisit the tasks that led to your suspension to understand the more appropriate action. Review resource links that may have been provided with your suspension. During your suspension, you will still have access to each queue’s Stats and History pages. If you have any questions about the review tasks that led to the suspension, post a question on Meta and use the `[review-suspension]` tag. In your post, be sure to include the following information:

- A link to the review that caused your suspension,
- An explanation of why you made the choice you did (particularly important if you feel the suspension is in error),
- A request to understand what the correct choice should have been and why.

In the future, take your time while reviewing and make sure each task is given adequate attention. If you're not certain what the correct action is, make use of the "Skip" feature and let someone else handle that review.

---

*[Подробнее про очереди проверок и как они работают](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/reviews-intro)*

Неверные проверки плохо влияют на сообщество. Если вы часто принимаете неверные решения в очередях, ваши привилегии на это будут *временно* ограничены, и вы не будете иметь доступ к очередям проверок на протяжении некоторого времени.

Если вы были отстранены от очередей проверок, вы увидите сообщение об этом в выпадающем меню очередей проверок. Подробную информацию об отстранении вы найдете на [странице проверок](/review). Такое уведомление будет отображаться до тех пор, пока ваши ограничение не будут сняты.

[image: Так выглядит выпадающее меню очередей проверок: слева - во время отстранения от проверок; справа - после окончания отстранения.]

> *Сообщения дословно: слева - "Ваши привилегии проверок отозваны до 24 июля. Нажмите, чтобы узнать больше", справа (ограничение снято, но сообщение все еще отображается) - "Ваши привилегии проверок были отозваны на 7 дней. Нажмите, чтобы узнать больше"*

Если вас отстранили от проверок на некоторый срок, но вы зашли на сайт только по истечению срок ограничения, вы получите специальное уведомление. Это уведомление пропадет, когда вы просмотрите его.

### Что мне делать, если меня отстранили?

Внимательно прочитайте уведомление. Просмотрите проверки, которые повлекли отстранение. Обратите внимание на ссылки, если они были предоставлены вам вместе с уведомлением.

Во время отстранения у вас будет доступ к статистике и истории очередей проверок. Если у вас возникнут вопросы о проверках, которые являются причиной отстранения, вы можете задать их на [Мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com), используя метку `[очередь-проверок]`. При публикации вопроса, обязательно включите в ваш вопрос следующие данные:

- Ссылка на проверку, которая повлекла отстранение,
- Ваша точка зрения насчет выбранного действия. Это особенно важно, если вы считаете, что произошла ошибка.
- Просьба объяснить, какие действия были правильными и почему.

В будущем старайтесь аккуратнее, не торопясь, выполнять задания в очередях, оказывая внимание каждому из них. Если вы не уверены, будут ли ваши действия правильными, или не знаете как поступить, просто нажмите кнопку «Пропустить», чтобы позволить другому человеку принять решение по данной задаче.

Comment: Интересно, а картинку тоже нужно будет переводить? :)

Comment: @МаксимФисман картинку лучше, конечно, сделать по текущему сайту.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Хах, но ее же можно сделать, только если кого-то suspend?!

Comment: @МаксимФисман действительно:) что ж, искусство требует жертв.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Скорее, точность*

Comment: В дальнейшем нужно: 1) Изменить картинку на русскую, 2) Обновить текст под картинкой (особенно исправить даты: числа и месяца)

Answer (score 2):

✅ Полностью переведено 
‍⚖️ Утверждено и добавлено

---

#### How do I use the Low-quality posts queue?

*Access earned at $Privilege-PostEditing reputation*
Posts entering the Low-quality posts queue have been [flagged as](/help/privileges/flag-posts)
problematic by users or recognized by
the system’s quality checks to be potentially low quality. This may
include:

- questions or answers that are very short, in the wrong
  language or gibberish.
- new or follow-up questions written as answers.
- answers that do not attempt to answer the question asked or contain
  only links and no explanation.
- comments entered as answers (“I have the
  same question” or “thanks for the great answer”).

It’s important to
remember that an incorrect answer is not “low quality” by our
definition. Incorrect answers should get a comment explaining any
issues or be downvoted, not flagged.

### Basic workflow

First, check to see if the post is a question or an answer; it will be labeled as "Question" or "Answer" at the top. The
majority of posts in this queue will be answers.

- Choose **Looks OK** for questions that are on-topic, sufficiently detailed
  and not too broad. Use this option for answers that answer the
  question as asked, even if they may be incorrect.
- **Edit** if the post is good quality, but you can improve the post to make it better. Avoid editing posts that should be closed or deleted, as it will remove the post from review.
- **Recommend deletion** or **Delete** if you think that an answer does not address the question at all, is link-only, or is incomprehensible. Do not vote to delete answers that are simply wrong. You may leave a comment explaining the issues with the answer, or choose one of the provided canned comments.
- **Recommend close** or **Close** if you think that a question should be closed (See [What does it mean if a question is](/help/closed-questions) “closed”?).
- **Skip** if you’re unsure about the post’s quality.

Some of the content of this page is adapted from information in our
[Meta Stack Exchange FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180029), which also contains more in-depth guidance if you are interested in reading more about this queue.

#### Как мне использовать очередь сообщений низкого качества?

*Доступ будет получен при достижении $Privilege-PostEditing баллов репутации*.

Сообщения, попавшие в очередь сообщений низкого качества, были [отмечены тревогами, как](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) проблемные участниками сообщества или системным контролем качества, как потенциально низкокачественные сообщения. Это могут быть:

- очень короткие вопросы или ответы, сообщения на другом языке или не имеющие смысла;
- новые или уточняющие вопросы, опубликованные как ответы;
- ответы, в которых не пытаются ответить на поставленный вопрос, или в которых содержатся лишь ссылки без пояснений.
- комментарии, добавленные в качестве ответов ("у меня тот же вопрос" или "спасибо за отличный ответ")

Важно помнить, что неправильный ответ в нашем понимании не является "ответом низкого качества". Неправильные ответы должны получать комментарии, разъясняющие любые аспекты, можно проголосовать против таких ответов, но не нужно отмечать их тревогой.

#### Базовое руководство

Сперва проверьте, является ли сообщение вопросом или ответом. Оно будет обозначено, как "Вопрос" или "Ответ" в шапке сообщения. Большинство постов в этой очереди будут ответами.

- Выберите **Выглядит нормально** для вопросов по теме, довольно подробных, но не  слишком общих. Используйте эту опцию для ответов, которые отвечают на поставленный вопрос, даже если такие ответы могут быть неправильными.
- **Редактируйте**, если сообщение высокого качества, но вы можете дополнить его и сделать лучше. Избегайте редактирования сообщений, которые должны быть закрыты или удалены, поскольку оно уберет такое сообщение из очереди проверок.
- **Рекомендуйте удаление** или **удаляйте** если вы считаете, что ответ совсем не подходит к этому вопросу, в нем содержится только ссылка или его невозможно понять. Не голосуйте за удаление ответов, которые просто неправильны. Вы можете оставить комментарий, объясняющий проблемы ответа или проголосовать за один из уже оставленных комментариев.
- **Рекомендуйте закрытие** или **закрывайте**, если считаете, что вопрос нужно закрыть. (Смотрите раздел [Что означает, статус вопроса "закрыт"?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)).
- Нажмите **пропустить**, если вы не уверены в своей оценке качества сообщения.

Часть содержимого этой страницы является переработанной информацией из наших  [Meta Stack Exchange FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155538/what-are-the-guidelines-for-reviewing/180029#180029), которые содержат более подробное руководство, если хотите прочесть больше об этой очереди.

Comment: @Akina исправил. Вы тоже можете улучшать перевод.

Comment: @Konstantin_SH *исправил* Ок. *Вы тоже можете улучшать перевод.* Нет уж... если я начну править - от первоначального текста мало что останется.

Comment: @Akina Ну, помните, что задача состоит в том, чтобы перевести текст, а не сочинять новый))

Comment: @Konstantin_SH Есть перевод "влоб, максимально близко к исходному тексту". Есть перевод "максимально близко по смыслу". Это принципиально разные вещи - порой даже для одного предложения, вне контекста, невозможно написать перевод, соответствующий обоим типам, что уж говорить о длинных текстах. Так что я, пожалуй, ограничусь точечными советами.

Answer (score 1):

✅ Переведено полностью

[статус-завершено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be)

---

#### Как пользоваться очередью первых сообщений?

*Очередь становится доступной при достижении $Privilege-AccessReviewQueues баллов репутации.*

Новые участники могут не до конца понимать как правильно задавать и отвечать на вопросы или могут не знать тематику сайта. Первые сообщения таких участников попадают в очередь первых сообщений. Эта очередь нужна, чтобы привлечь особое внимание к участникам, которым, возможно, нужна помощь в ознакомлении с сайтом, и их сообщениям.

### Основы рабочего процесса

Во время проверки вам могут встретиться как вопросы, которым необходима правка, как и те, которые не требуют никаких действий. Сделайте все необходимое, что сообщение могло остаться на сайте. Например, вам может встретится хороший вопрос по теме сайта, которому просто необходима небольшая помощь в форматировании. В таком случае исправьте форматирование и, если хотите, проголосуйте «за» и нажмите «Готово».

- Выберите «Действий не требуется», если с сообщением все отлично.
- Выберите «Готово», если вы

  - **Проголосовали** «за» или «против» сообщения.
  - **Отредактировали** тематичное понятное сообщение (или предложили правку), которое нуждалось в небольшой правке (грамматика, правописание или форматирование).
  - **Прокомментировали** сообщение (или проголосовали за существующие комментарии) чтобы указать на то, что вопросу или ответу чего-то не хватает или требуется исправление иного типа. Такие комментарии могут быть полезны как автору самого вопроса, так и остальным проверяющим.
  - **Отметили сообщение тревогой** как спам или грубое или оставили сигнал тревоги на ответе, который не пытается ответить на вопрос или состоит из одной ссылки.
  - [Проверенные участники](/help/privileges/trusted-user) могут также **голосовать за удаление** ответов, которые не пытаются ответить на вопрос, являются ответами-ссылками или дубликатами других ответов.
- Выберите «Пропустить», если вы не уверены, что делать.

Одной проверки достаточно, чтобы закрыть задание. Пожалуйста, проверяйте внимательно соответствует ли сообщение критериям качества сайта. Некоторые советы по принятию решений во время проверки новых сообщений:

#### Для всех сообщений

- Если сообщение является спамом или содержит рекламные ссылки, помечайте его тревогой как «спам».
- Если сообщение оскорбительно, помечайте его тревогой как «грубый или оскорбительный».

#### Для вопросов

- Проверьте, что основная часть вопроса находится в самом сообщении, а не на стороннем сайте. Если вопрос содержит ссылки на другие сайты, то он должен быть написан так, что будет иметь смысл, даже если ссылки станут неработающими.
- Вопрос должен:

  - быть ясным;
  - иметь всю необходимую для ответа информацию;
  - быть по теме сайта;
  - запрашивать ответы, основанных на фактах;
  - показывать стремление разобраться;
  - иметь подходящими метки.
- Если необходимо, попросите у автора необходимую информацию, чтобы сузить вопрос, либо переформулируйте вопрос сами, чтобы он соответствовал тематике сайта.
- Если вам кажется, что вы уже видели похожий вопрос раньше, проверьте, не является вопрос дубликатом.
- Проголосуйте «за» хороший, правильно написанный вопрос.
- Некоторые вопросы следует закрывать через [тревогу](/help/privileges/flag-posts) или [голос за закрытие](/help/privileges/close-questions). О том, какие вопросы следует закрывать, вы можете узнать [здесь](/help/closed-questions).

#### Для ответов

- Убедитесь, что автор отвечает на сам вопрос, а не комментирует или задает другой вопрос.
- Ответ должен отличаться от других.
- Ответ не должен содержать «мертвые» ссылки или состоять только из ссылок.

Вы можете узнать, как более эффективно редактировать вопросы и ответы, в статье [«Как работает система редактирования?»](/help/editing)

Некоторая информация в этой статье была взята со страницы часто задаваемых вопросов: [Meta Stack Exchange FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180030). Там вы можете найти более подробное руководство об очереди проверок «первых сообщений».

Answer (score 1):

[статус-завершено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be)

✅ Переведено полностью

---

#### How do I use the Suggested edits queue?

*Access earned at $Privilege-PostEditing reputation*
The primary purpose of the Suggested edits queue is to review edits contributed by users who have less than
$Privilege-PostEditing reputation and determine if the suggested edits
are beneficial to the post. Suggested edits should focus on improving
grammar, spelling, and formatting, all while maintaining the author’s
original intent.

For users with $Privilege-ApproveTagWikiEdits reputation, you may also see tag wiki edit suggestions in this queue. For more information about handling these reviews, see the [approve tag wiki edits](/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) privilege page.

### Basic workflow

Start by reading the edit summary and looking at the differences between the original post and the edit. Be sure to check
the title (and tags, if a question) to see if they were edited, and
check the comments section for any information that the author may
have included only in comments.

- **Approve** if the edit improves the post and doesn’t need any additional edits.
- **Improve edit** if the edit is good but incomplete, and use the edit window to fix any outstanding issues.
- **Reject** if the edit is unnecessary, destructive, or counter to the
  original author’s intent.
- **Reject and edit** if the suggested edit makes
  the post worse or doesn’t solve critical issues with the post. Then add
  your own edit - this will open an edit window allowing you to improve
  the post.
- **Skip** if you’re unsure whether the post was improved or not

### Common reasons to Approve

- Adds additional information or clarifies existing answer.
- Improves grammar, spelling or formatting of the post
  or other minor mistakes.
- Edits in information found in comments.
- Updates an answer if more information is available or something has
  changed.
- Adds links to sources or citations.

### Common reasons to Reject

When rejecting an edit, you’ll need to choose a rejection reason.
These are a good outline for the reasons you may need to reject a
suggested edit:

- Spam or vandalism

  - adds irrelevant or unattributed promotional links or
    mentions of products.
  - damages or destroys the content of the post.
- No improvement whatsoever

  - changes to content or formatting that are
    unnecessary or make the post more confusing.
  - changes to grammar,
    spelling,  or style that are unnecessary.
- Irrelevant tags

  - tags should
    clearly indicate the subject of the question; reject edits that add
    tags that are tangential or incorrect.
- Clearly conflicts with author’s
  intent

  - changes a post to say the opposite, or something very different
    from what the original post read.
- Attempt to reply

  - introduces a request for clarification or question to the post’s author that should have been a comment or answer.
- Causes harm

  - This reason can be used in cases where a suggestion should be prevented but none of the above or several of the above apply. You should explain why you are rejecting the suggestion so that other reviewers can understand your action.

Some of the content of this page is adapted from information in our
[Meta Stack Exchange FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/155539), which also contains more in-depth guidance if
you are interested in reading more about this queue.

---

#### Как пользоваться очередью «Предлагаемые правки»?

*Очередь становится доступной при достижении $Privilege-PostEditing баллов репутации*

Очередь «Предлагаемые правки» дает возможность сообществу проверять правки, предложенные участниками с репутацией ниже $Privilege-PostEditing. Хорошие правки направлены на улучшение грамматики и форматирования, а также устранение опечаток, сохраняя при этом первоначальный замысел автора.

Участникам с репутацией выше $Privilege-ApproveTagWikiEdits также доступны к проверке предложения по улучшению описания меток. Больше информации об изменении описания меток доступно на странице: «[Изменение описания меток](/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits)».

### Основы рабочего процесса

Начните проверку правки с ее описания и затем просмотрите предлагаемые изменения. Не забудьте проверить заголовок и метки, если это вопрос и метки или заголовок  были изменены. Обратите внимание на комментарии: возможно, автор правки оставил там какие-либо дополнения.

- **Примите** правку, если считаете, что она полезна и не нуждается в улучшении.
- **Улучшите** правку, если считаете ее полезной, но неполной. Для улучшения вы можете использовать окно редактирования.
- **Отклоните** правку, если считаете ее бесполезной, вредной или изменяющей первоначальный замысел автора.
- **Отклоните и исправьте**, если считаете, что предлагаемая правка делает сообщение хуже или не является полезной при том, что сообщение нуждается в правке. Свою правку вы можете внести через окно редактирования.
- **Пропустите**, если вы не уверены, является ли правка полезной.

### Распространенные причины принятия правки

- Добавляет или уточняет важную информацию.
- Исправляет грамматику, опечатки, форматирование или другие небольшие ошибки.
- Добавляет информацию из комментариев.
- Обновляет ответ в случае появления более актуальной информации.
- Добавляет ссылки на ресурсы или цитаты.

### Распространенные причины отклонения правки

Отклоняя правку, необходимо указать причину. Существуют следующие причины для отклонения правки:

- Спам или вандализм

  - Ссылки на неуместные материалы или информация нарушающая авторские права.
  - Вандализм содержимого сообщения.
- Не является правкой

  - Делает сообщение трудным для восприятия, вносит изменения, не являющиеся необходимыми.
  - Изменяет грамматику, опечатки или стиль без видимой необходимости.
- Несоответствующие метки

  - Метки должны ясно указывать на суть вопроса. Следует отклонять правки, добавляющие неправильные, устаревшие или несоответствующие теме вопроса метки.
- Явно противоречит намерениям автора

  - Изменяет сообщение так, что его содержимое изменяется на совершенно другое вплоть до противоположного.
- Уточнение или ответ

  - Представляет собой запрос информации о вопросе или ответ на вопрос.
- Несет вред

  - Данную причину следует использовать, когда правку следует отклонить, однако ни одна из вышеперечисленных причин не подходит. В таком случае вам следует описать, почему вы считаете, что данная правка неуместна, чтобы остальные участники могли понять ваши действия.

Некоторая информация данной статьи была взята со страницы часто задаваемых вопросов: [Meta Stack Exchange FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/155539). Там вы можете найти более подробное руководство об очереди проверок «Предлагаемые правки».

Answer (score 1):

✅ Переведено полностью

---

#### How do I use the Close votes queue?

*Access earned at $Privilege-CloseQuestion reputation*

The Close votes  queue includes questions that other users have flagged as needing to  be closed. Before reviewing in this queue, you should be familiar with what sorts of questions should and should not be closed. To find that information, see the following two pages:

- [Closed question help article](/help/closed-questions) is a network-wide guide for the primary reasons questions should be closed. This generally happens when a question:

  - is a [duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates) of an existing question on the site.
  - needs additional details or clarity to be answered.
  - needs to be more focused, as the existing question is too broad.
  - is an opinion-based question that doesn’t have an objectively correct answer.
- [On topic article](/help/on-topic) is a site-specific guide to what types of questions are on and off topic on this site. This page will differ on each site on the Network.

### Basic workflow

At the top of the review task page, you’ll find the reasons others flagged or voted the question to be closed, but if you disagree, you may choose a different option. The close reason that gets the most votes will be indicated on the post if it is closed. Review the question content completely and then make a decision from one of the options:

- **Close** the question if it is a duplicate, lacks sufficient detail,
  needs to be narrowed in scope, is opinion based, is off topic, or if
  it meets one of the other community-specific reasons to close. Choose
  the applicable close reason based on your assessment. You also have
  the option to enter a custom reason if none of the existing ones
  apply.
- **Leave open** if none of the above is the case.
- **Edit** should be reserved for when the question is close-worthy as written, but when you believe you can rescue the question to make it fit the scope. This may mean adding in details the asker left in comments or making slight adjustments to an opinion-based question so that it's objective. Don’t make minor edits if the question would be closed even with these changes, as it will remove the question from review.
- **Skip** any time you’re not certain - don’t be afraid to use the skip button! Focus on reviewing posts you’re certain of rather than ones you need to guess how to handle.

**Tip:** You may want to restrict which questions you are shown to subjects you are familiar with by filtering reviews by tags you have experience in. You can do this by clicking “Filter” in the top section of a review task. When in doubt, choose Skip.

[image: Close votes filters]

Note: If you choose two tags, you will find all reviews with one or both tags. Filters will not restrict to reviews with both tags only.

Some of the content of this page is adapted from information in our [Meta Stack Exchange FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180032), which also contains more in-depth guidance if you are interested in reading more about this queue.

---

#### Как использовать очередь проверок "Голоса за закрытие"?

*Очередь становится доступной при достижении $Privilege-CloseQuestion баллов репутации*

Очередь проверок "Голоса за закрытие" содержит вопросы, которые другие пользователи отметили тревогой. Для проверки вопросов этой очереди, вам следует знать, какие вопросы стоит закрывать. Вы можете найти эту инфомрацию на следующих страницах:

- [Что означает статус вопроса «закрыт» или «требует правки»?](/help/closed-questions) - это руководство по причинам для закрытия вопросов. Обычно, такое такое случается, если вопрос:

  - является [дубликатом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) уже существующего вопроса.
  - нуждается в деталях или уточнениях
  - является слишком общим
  - подразумевает ответы, основанные на мнениях, а не на фактах.
- [На какие темы здесь можно задавать вопросы?](/help/on-topic) - это руководство о том, какие вопросы соответствуют теме сайта, а какие - нет. Эта страница будет отличаться на разных сайтах сети.

### Основы рабочего процесса

В верхней части окна этой очереди проверок указана причина, по которой другие пользователи отметили вопрос тревогой или проголосовали за его закрытие. Если вы не согласны с этой причиной, вы можете выбрать другую. Причина закрытия, которая наберет больше голосов, будет отображена в вопросе, если он будет закрыт. После проверки причины тревоги, внимательно прочитайте содержание вопроса и выберите одну из следующих опций:

- **Закрыть** вопрос, если он является дубликатом; нуждается в деталях или дополнениях; является слишком общим; предполагает ответы, основанные на фактах; не соответствует теме сайта или удовлетворяет другой причине закрытия. Вы также можете указать собственную причину, если ни одна из вышеперечисленных не подходит.
- **Оставить открытым**, если действия не требуются
- **Редактировать**, если вопрос плохо написан, однако вы считаете, что можете улучшить его и сделать более подходящим тематике сайта. Вы можете добавить детали, оставленные автором вопроса в комментариях, или внести небольшие корректировки в вопрос, чтобы он предполагал ответы, основанные на фактах. Вам не следует вносить в вопрос незначительные правки, если вы считаете, что он все равно будет закрыт, потому что это может удалить вопрос из очереди проверок, оставив его некачественным.
- **Пропустить**, если вы не можете принять решение. Не бойтесь использовать кнопку пропуска! Лучше сконцентрируйтесь на проверке вопросов, в которых вы можете принять точное решение, чем тех, в которых вы сомневаетесь, какие действия надо предпринять.

**Подсказка:** Вы можете выбрать вопросы, которые будут вам предлагаться для проверки, с помощью фильтрации очереди по меткам. Для этого нажмите "Фильтр" в верхней части страницы.

[image: Фильтр вопросов в очереди]

Обратите внимание на то, что если вы выберите 2 метки, то вам будут предложены вопросы, содержащие *хотя бы одну* из них.

Некоторая информация данной статьи была взята со страницы часто задаваемых вопросов: Meta Stack Exchange FAQ. Там вы можете найти более подробное руководство, если хотите узнать больше информации об очереди проверок "Голоса за закрытие".

Answer (score 1):

✅ Переведено полностью

---

#### How do I use the Reopen votes queue?

*Access earned at $Privilege-CloseQuestion reputation*
Any closed question that has received one reopen vote gets added to this queue,
as well as any question edited within 70 days since its closure.
Before reviewing in this queue, you should be familiar with what sorts
of questions should and should not be closed. To find that
information, see the following two pages:

- [Closed question help article](/help/closed-questions) is a
  network-wide guide for the primary reasons questions should be closed.
  This generally happens when a question:

  - is a duplicate of an existing question on the site.
  - needs additional details or clarity to be answered.
  - needs to be more focused, as the existing question is too broad.
  - is an opinion-based question that doesn’t have an objectively correct answer.
- [On topic article](/help/on-topic) is a site-specific guide to
  what types of questions are on and off topic on this site. This page
  will differ on each site on the Network.

### Basic workflow

Evaluate the question as it is now. Review any edits that may have been made after the question was closed and any comments
on the question. If edits were made but are insufficient to reopen the
question, consider leaving a comment explaining why.

- **Leave closed** if close reason(s) still apply. Do not reopen if the
  specific reason for closure no longer applies, but the question should
  still be closed. Consider leaving a comment to explain why the question should remain closed, particularly if the reason is different than what appears in the banner.
- **Edit and reopen** if you can resolve issues with the
  question yourself, and these edits are sufficient for the post to be
  reopened. Avoid making minor edits that don’t impact whether the post
  should be reopened.
- **Reopen** if issues with the question have been
  resolved, or if it was incorrectly closed.
- **Skip** if you're not sure
  whether the question should be reopened.

**Tip:** You may want to restrict which questions you are shown to subjects you are familiar with by filtering reviews by tags you have
experience in. You can do this by clicking “Filter” in the top section
of a review task. When in doubt, choose Skip.

[image: Reopen votes filter]

Some of the content of this page is adapted from information in our
[Meta Stack Exchange FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180450), which also contains more in-depth
guidance if you are interested in reading more about this queue.

---

#### Как использовать очередь проверок "Голоса за переоткрытие"

*Очередь становится доступной при достижении $Privilege-CloseQuestion баллов репутации*

В эту очередь попадают закрытые вопросы, которые получили как минимум 1 голос за переоткрытие или были отредактированы не более 70 дней с момента закрытия. Перед проверкой вопросов этой очереди, ознакомьтесь с тем, какие вопросы следует оставлять закрытыми, а какие - переоткрывать. Вы можете прочитать об этом на следующих страницах:

- [Что означает статус вопроса «закрыт» или «требует правки»?](/help/closed-questions) - это руководство по причинам для закрытия вопросов. Обычно, такое случается, если вопрос:

  - является дубликатом уже существующего вопроса.
  - нуждается в деталях или уточнениях
  - является слишком общим
  - подразумевает ответы, основанные на мнениях, а не на фактах.
- [На какие темы здесь можно задавать вопросы?](/help/on-topic) - это руководство о том, какие вопросы соответствуют теме сайта, а какие - нет. Эта страница будет отличаться на разных сайтах сети.

### Основы рабочего процесса

Оцените вопрос таким, какой он есть. Проверьте: возможно, в вопросе были внесены правки или оставлены какие-либо комментарии уже после его закрытия. Если это так, и правки действительно были внесены, однако их недостаточно для переоткрытия вопроса, вы можете оставить комментарий, объяснив, почему вы так считаете.

- **Оставить закрытым**, если причины, по которым он был закрыт, остались. Не открывайте вопрос, если причина закрытия уже не применяется, однако вопрос все равно не заслуживает переоткрытия. Вы так же можете оставить комментарий, объясняющий, почему вопрос стоит оставить закрытым, особенно если причина по вашему мнению отличается от той, что указана в сообщении о закрытии.
- **Править и переоткрыть**, если вы можете решить проблемы вопроса самостоятельно, и ваших действий будет достаточно, чтобы переоткрыть вопрос. Не следует вносить мелких правок, если их недостаточно для возвращения вопроса.
- **Переоткрыть**, если причины закрытия были устранены, или вопрос был закрыт по ошибке.
- **Пропустить**, если вы не уверены в правильности решения, сомневаетесь или не можете принять его.

**Подсказка:** Вы можете выбрать вопросы, которые будут вам предлагаться для проверки, с помощью фильтрации очереди по меткам. Для этого нажмите "Фильтр" в верхней части страницы.

[image: Reopen votes filter]

Некоторая информация данной статьи была взята со страницы часто задаваемых вопросов: [Meta Stack Exchange FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180450). Там вы можете найти более подробное руководство, если хотите узнать больше информации об очереди проверок "Голоса за закрытие".

Answer (score 1):

✅ Переведено полностью

---

#### How do I use the Late Answers queue?

*Access earned at $Privilege-AccessReviewQueues reputation
The Late Answers queue contains answers that were posted by new users much
later than when the question was asked. Late answers tend to be seen
by fewer people than answers posted soon after the question was asked,
so the review queue helps ensure that these answers meet the same
quality standards as all other answers.

While many late answers are merely saying “Thanks!” or are attempts to
ask follow-up questions and should be deleted, in other cases it may
require specific knowledge of the topic. If you’re unsure whether the
answer actually attempts to answer the question, use the “Skip”
option.

### Basic workflow

When reviewing, you may do one or more of several actions or you may do none. Perform all actions that you deem
necessary. For example, an answer may be complete and do a good job of
answering the question, but need formatting help. In this case, edit to
improve the formatting and - if you wish - upvote it before clicking "I'm done".

- Choose **No action needed** if the answer requires no intervention
- Select **I’m done** if/when
  you’ve completed any of the following:

  - **Vote** up or down.
  - **Edit** (or
    suggest an edit) if the answer is clear and within guidelines, but
    could use some editing help to improve grammar, spelling, or
    formatting.
  - **Comment** to point out content that is missing or may need
    adjusting. These comments can be useful to both the post author and
    other reviewers.
  - **Flag** posts that are spam or rude, as well as answers that don't attempt to answer the question or are link-only.
  - [Trusted users](/help/privileges/trusted-user) may also **Delete** answers that don’t attempt to answer the question, are
    link-only, or are duplicates of other answers.
- **Skip** if you’re unsure about what to do

### Common Late answers

- Spam or self-promotion

  - If the answer meets the [description for acceptable self-promotion](/help/promotion), add a
    comment mentioning this to reduce the chance of other reviewers
    marking it spam. If it does not, add a comment linking to the help
    center article and encourage the author to edit the post to meet our
    guidelines. If it unequivocally looks like spam, flag it as such.
- Non-answers

  - Answers thanking the author of the question or one of its
    answers, asking a new question, stating that they have the same problem, or asking for clarification from the author. These should be deleted.

For more information on how to edit effectively, please see our [Help center article about editing](/help/editing).

Some of the content of this page is adapted from information in our
[Meta Stack Exchange FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180031), which also contains more in-depth
guidance if you are interested in reading more about this queue.

---

#### Как использовать очередь проверки "Запоздалые ответы"?

*Очередь становится доступной при достижении $Privilege-AccessReviewQueues баллов репутации*

В очередь "Запоздалые ответы" попадают ответы, которые были даны новыми участниками гораздо позде публикации вопроса. В отличие от ответов к новым вопросам, запоздалые ответы обычно видят меньше людей, поэтому с помощью этой очереди можно проверить такие ответы согласно тем же правилам и стандартам.

Некоторые запоздалые ответы просто содержат благодарность или являются новыми вопросами — такие ответы следует удалять. В других случаях могут потребоваться специфические знания темы. Если вы не уверены, является ли ответ полезным, вам следует использовать опцию "Пропустить".

### Основы рабочего процесса.

При проверке вы можете совершить одно или несколько действий над ответом либо не сделать ничего. Сделайте всё, что считаете нужным. Например, если ответ полный и точно отвечает на вопрос, но имеет проблемы с форматированием, вы можете это исправить и - если хотите - проголосовать "за" перед нажатием "Завершить".

- **Выглядит нормально**, если сообщение не требует действий.
- **Править**, если нужно улучшить внешний вид, ясность или точность сообщения
- **Рекомендовать удаление или удалить**, если сообщение нельзя улучшить правками и он не является ответом.
- **Просмотрено**, если вы выполнили хотя бы одно из следующих действий:

  - **Проголосовали** для отражения качества и полезности сообщения.
  - **Оставили комментарий**, чтобы дать автору конструктивную обратную связь, или проголосовали за существующие комментарии.
  - **Отметили тревогой** серьёзные проблемы
- **Пропустить**, если вы не уверены, что делать.

### Частые случаи запоздалых ответов

- Спам или реклама

  - Если ответ **не** нарушает правила [Как не быть спамером](/help/promotion), оставьте комментарий и отметьте, что не считаете ответ спамом, чтобы снизить вероятность того, что другие првоеряющие отметят его как спам. Вы также можете оставить автору в коммнтариях ссылку на руководство и попросить автора отредактировать ответ, чтобы он соответствовал правилам. Если овтет однозначно является спамом, вам стоит пометить его тревогой.
- Не является ответом

  - Ответы-благодарности, ответы-новые вопросы и тому подобное стоит удалять.

Чтобы получить больше информации о том, как эффективно править, посетите страницу о [системе редактирвоания](/help/editing).

Некоторая информация данной статьи была взята со страницы часто задаваемых вопросов: [Meta Stack Exchange FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180031). Там вы можете найти более подробное руководство, если хотите узнать больше информации об очереди проверок "Запоздалые ответы".