# И снова перевод! На этот раз справки

Tags: дефект, локализация

Общаясь с новичком, захотел сослаться на статью из справки, а там такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для ряда статей отсутствует перевод.
Непорядок!

надо бы перевести.

Вот список статей из справки без перевода:

**Очереди проверок**

- [How do I use the Close votes queue?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/review-close)
- [How do I use the Reopen votes queue?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/review-reopen)
- [How do I use the Late Answers queue?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/review-late-answers)

**Репутация и модерация**

- [Moderator Agreement policies](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mod-agreement-policies)

Comment: По модераторскому соглашению тоже [есть уже](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2109/176217)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, английский текст, видимо, изменился. значит, надо и перевод пересмотреть.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin текст чего именно изменился? Справка по очередям ведь до конца и не была ещё переведена.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, в возможном дубликате был сделан перевод оригинальных английских заголовков и текстов. вроде бы, они были добавлены в базу переводов. если были опубликованы, то теперь по ссылкам фигурируют опять английский текст и заголовки. преполагаю, что произошло это из-за изменений в этом самом тексте (и заголовках). если так и есть, то перевод надо пересматривать.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin если и так, то делать это надо под вопросом от КМ, а не тут, имхо. Т.к. та работа фактически ещё не была закончена.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, Если переводы не были опубликованы то логично продолжить в обсуждении Николаса, если они были опубликованы, но потом слетели то это может быть `дефект` и его можно здесь доделать.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, По мне так где хотите доделывайте. Главное не потеряйте вопрос КМ, который уже 8 месяцев назад был задан и не забудьте про все это.

Comment: Просто переводы интерфейса - это одно, их можно делать через traducir. А переводы справки - совсем другое, там участие КМ обязательно.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, я понимаю. И прошлые комментарии - не выпад в Вашу сторону. Я представляю сколько вы сделали для сервиса в области переводов на русский. Просто я совсем не в теме переводов и не хочу чтобы вопрос потерялся. Если вы считаете, что вопрос нужно закрыть как дубликат и лучше вернуться к прошлому вопросу - то давайте так и сделаем.

Comment: Просто @aleksandrbarakin утверждает, что перевод был сделан. Но глядя на  [вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11114/176217) как раз видно, что упомянутые три раздела не переведены, что как раз соответствует выделенным на вашей картинке. Поэтому я и предлагаю это к закрытию как дубликат, а не что-то сломанное с прошлого раза.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, да, я видел. В самом вопросе эти статьи не отмечены переведенными. Но на соответствующих ответах стоит отметка "Переведен полностью", которая правда была поставлена не Николасом, а автором перевода... в общем нужно реанимировать этот вопрос, проверить корректность предоставленных переводов и если все ок, то нужно попросить Николаса опубликовать статьи...а если нет, то нужно будет отредактировать варианты переводов и довести их до ума...но в любом случае неплохо было бы как то поднять этот вопрос в топ, чтобы привлечь к нему внимание.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ,да. На всех этих ответах стоит отметка "Переведен полностью" и все их поставил Максим Фисман самовольно, чем возможно и запутал всех...Отметку такую, насколько я понимаю должен был ставить Николас после публикации.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, и внимательнее изучив вопрос становится ясно, что вы правы. Переводы не были согласованы,утверждены и опубликованы и что работа над данными переводами не была завершена.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Перевод, на который вы ссылаетесь — это перевод самого соглашения. В этом вопросе ссылка на страницу справки. Само соглашение нам не дадут перевести, потому что оно имеет юридическую силу. Справку перевести было бы здорово.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky на какой перевод я ссылаюсь и где?