# Не могу войти в аккаунт stack overflow через Vk

Tags: дефект, поддержка, статус-завершено, вконтакте

Уже более 3х недель не получается войти в аккаунт через ВК.
При входе такая ошибка

> There was an error fetching your account from VK. Please try logging in again.

Как мне вернуть мой аккаунт?

Comment: А сейчас как зашли?  Текущему профилю почти 3 года.

Comment: Этот аккаунт через гугл зарегистрирован - не помню почему я на вк перешел, но есть у меня и запасной вариант, так сказать)

Comment: так можно к одному аккаунту несколько разных способов входа привязать. Если укажите другой, можно попробовать объединить аккаунты. Хотя проблему вк это, конечно, вряд ли решит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это дефект. В пятницу отправил запрос разработчикам, они подтвердили. Связано с переходом VK на новую версию API. В ближайшее время исправим.

**Обновление**

Поправили.

Comment: обратите пожалуйста внимание, что у нас не все переводы страниц для справки утверждены(плюс прибавились новые непереведенные страницы) см. Вопрос https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11670/%d0%98-%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%9d%d0%b0-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%be%d1%82-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8 и обсуждение в нем, а также связанный вопрос. Уже полгода висят, бедные (((

Comment: @МихаилРебров Большое спасибо! Завтра на свежую голову посмотрю все!

Comment: Да, спасибо, я смог войти) Причем я недавно задавал вопрос, почему у меня перестал работать бот в вк) Там тоже нужно было версию API изменить, хах)

Comment: @МихаилРебров Буду вам признателен, если вы предложите вариант перевода в вопросе: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11114/6 Я сразу после обновлю справку. Спасибо!

Comment: Добрый день, снова проблема с авторизацией через вк. При нажатии на кнопку войти через вк открывается страница с черным экраном и надписью errot

Comment: @Влад Здравствуйте! Не могли бы вы прислать детали вашего окружения через [форму обратной связи](/contact)?

Comment: Я написал, мне сказали ждать. Но сколько мне, блин, ждать, я уже месяц, наверное, войти не могу, как жить?